# ios swift parse: Put all related data into one object

Tags: ios, swift, object, parse-platform

when I query my class I also need its pointer data. While be `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` method I would like to have all the data combined into one object. This is my query so far:

```
func fetchAllObjects(){

        PFObject.unpinAllObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)

        var query = PFQuery(className: "CardSet")
        query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
        query.includeKey("lesson")

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

            if (error == nil) {

                for object in objects{

                    var lesson: PFObject = object["lesson"] as PFObject
                    // how do I get the lessons object into the cardset object?

                }

                PFObject.pinAllInBackground(objects, block: nil)

            }else{
                println(error.userInfo)
            }
        }

    }
```

As I want to pin the entire object with all related data in line `PFObject.pinAllInBackground(objects, block: nil)` I need to pack the `lesson` object into the `CardSet` object.

How can I do that?

Comment: According to the [Parse Docs about pinning](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#localdatastore-pin/iOS) "You can store a PFObject in the local datastore by pinning it. Pinning a PFObject is recursive, just like saving, so any objects that are pointed to by the one you are pinning will also be pinned." So aslong as you include in your query, all the retrieved included objects will also be pinned. Once again, according to the Docs.

Comment: In that case I have only the objectId of the pointer lesson pinned, but not its field "name". And this is the information I want to access together with the CardSet object details. What can I do to have all the data from cardSet **and** Lesson available to fill for example a tableview cell?

Comment: So if you were to do something like var lessonName: let = lesson["name"] as let? (sorry for my horrid swift), and this will return either nothing or a "column not found"? Oh and another question on top, just to be sure, you save the pointer inside the database as a pointer and not as an array of object_ids? (As described under the possible ways of saving [Relations](https://parse.com/docs/relations_guide) part of their Docs)

Comment: I saved the lessons as pointer for sure.
When I just query the CardSet as in the query above (without accessing the lesson as PFObject) and try to access it later on (for example in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` by 
`let lesson: PFObject = object["lesson"] as PFObject`
`var lessonName = lessonObject["name"] as? String`
I get a message that I have to use `fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock` to get the data. And this is what I think can be avoided to have just another request, as the data I need can be fetched in the query before `fetchAllObjects`. Hope this makes it clearer? Thanks for your help!

Comment: It indeed can be avoided, I've managed to accomplish this with some horrid workaround I now realise. I made a custom class that extended a PFObject, but in general it gave me a headache to work with it. So before I'll go on about that, I was curious is perhaps the multi-level annotation works? e.g. query.includeKey("lesson"), query.includeKey("lesson.name")? It's worth a try!

Comment: But what I did was use [subclasses](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#subclasses/iOS) and store lessondata objects inside the subclass for CardSet, and then pin CardSet. So that when I would retrieve CardSet I know for sure I also have the lessons. But this is how far my knowledge (and annoyance) about Parse goes. I hope it can be some kind of help to you!

Comment: If I try to get lesson.name I get the error: field "name" cannot be included because it is not a pointer to another object. I have to say that I don't understand anything about subclasses yet :( If there would be a way of extending my result object with the lesson object I could try to continue from there...

Comment: Alright, well it was worth a try, but yeah lemme see if I can cook something together here. EDIT: Ohyeah, btw [Subclasses](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#subclasses/iOS)

Comment: You  would be my hero of the day :) Thanks so much!! I highly appreciate your help and time!!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first of all, I'm not that experienced when it comes to Swift, or Objective-C. But the basics of Parse remains the same over all coding languages, so I'll try to make it as understandable as any gibberish can be.

Second, I've got the information from [the Parse iOS docs]

**Subclassing PFObject**

To create a PFObject subclass:

1. Declare a subclass which conforms to the PFSubclassing protocol.
2. Implement the class method parseClassName. This is the string you
   would pass to initWithClassName: and makes all future class name
   references unnecessary.
3. Import PFObject+Subclass in your .m file (Objective-C) or bridge
   header file (Swift). This implements all methods in PFSubclassing
   beyond parseClassName.
4. Call [YourClass registerSubclass] before Parse
   setApplicationId:clientKey:. An easy way to do this is with your
   class' +load method in Objective-C or with +initialize in Swift.

This is the basic setup for CardSet

```
// Import this header into your Swift bridge header file to
// let Armor know that PFObject privately provides most of
// the methods for PFSubclassing.

#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>

// CardSet.swift

class CardSet : PFObject, PFSubclassing {
  override class func initialize() {
    var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
      self.registerSubclass()
    }
  }

  static func lessons() -> [Lesson] {
    return @"lesson"
  }

  static func parseClassName() -> String! {
    return "CardSet"
  }
}

// CardSet.h
@interface Armor : PFObject<PFSubclassing>
+ ([Lesson] *)lessons;
@property (retain) Lesson *lessons;
+ (NSString *)parseClassName;
@property (retain) NSString *displayName;
@end
```

And this is the subclass for lessons

```
// Import this header into your Swift bridge header file to
// let Armor know that PFObject privately provides most of
// the methods for PFSubclassing.

#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>

// Lesson.swift

class Lesson: PFObject, PFSubclassing {
  override class func initialize() {
    var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
      self.registerSubclass()
    }
  }

  static func lessonName() -> String {
    return @"name"
  }

  static func parseClassName() -> String! {
    return "Lesson"
  }
}

// CardSet.h
@interface Armor : PFObject<PFSubclassing>
+ ([Lesson] *)lessons;
@property (retain) NSString *lessons;
+ (NSString *)parseClassName;
@property (retain) NSString *displayName;
@end
```

You can access the displayName property using armor.displayName or and assign to it using armor.displayName = @"Wooden Shield"

```
let query = CardSet.query()
query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
query.includeKey("lesson")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {

            for object in objects{
                var lesson: Lesson = object.lesson //Since it automatically loaded the data inside the subclass, you don't actually have to set any variable

            }

            PFObject.pinAllInBackground(objects, block: nil)

        }else{
            println(error.userInfo)
        }
    }
```

Now there are a couple of important rules to remember:

First is already discussed in 4., but I'd like to adress it again, before you do '[Parse setApplicationId:clientKey:]' you have to **register** these subclasses for **Parse to recognize them as subclasses of PFObject**. (See 4.)

Since you're subclassing both CardSet and Lessons from PFObject it's important to remember that your subclasses contain methods for all database fields, which you otherwise cannot access.

I hope this helps a bit and can give you a start on subclassing!

Disclaimer:
I have a limited experience with the iOS programming languages and can almost guaruntee with absolute certainty that this code has some compilation issues. On top of that, most of the information I have tried to provide here are based on issues I've had to deal with before inside my own project, including pinning objects and their pointers respectively.

Comment: Ok, I will go through slowly and carefully! Thanks for everything!